# How to use a rank formula that ignores errors

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to build a rank formula that ignores errors.

I've tried:

```
=Rank(BN4,(if(iserror(BQ4:BQ31),"",BQ4:BQ31)))
```

I've also Tried:

```
  =IF(ISERROR($BQ$4:$BQ$31),"",1+SUMPRODUCT($BP$4:$BP$31=BP4,$BQ$4:$BQ$31>BQ4))
```

Is There something wrong with the formula? Is there a better way? See image below, the rank formula appears in Col BN. Thanks!

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbEc9.png)

Comment: I found this link from google-ing. https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/886607-the-rank-function-cannot-ignore-error-values.html

Answer (score 2):

Given the spreadsheet below:

[image]

You can use the following formula on C2 and drag it:

```
=IF(ISERR(A2),"",COUNTIF($A$2:$A$7,">"&A2)+1)
```

Comment: I think that's what I'm doing? Just w/ sumproduct

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what's going on: in your second formula, your Sumproduct is still calculated with the errors. Although the first part your formula tells Excel to return a Blank when calculating the rank of an ERROR, the errors are stil inputted into second part where you actually calculate the rank, and thus Excel will spit out an Error even if it's calculating the rank of a regular number

The formula provided by Lucas above is probably the simplest way. If you must use sumproduct, you should include something in your sumproduct that tells excel to use a blank value if it comes across an error when calculating the some product.

For example, if you're trying to do the sumproduct of A1:A4 and B1:4 but the both ranges have some errors, then you'd use:

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(IF(ISNA(A1:A4),0,A1:A4),IF(ISNA(B1:B4),0,B1:B4))
```

Comment: Usually, when mentioning another's answer in a different one, I add a link (from "share" under their answer). This is because a verbal mentioning can be insufficient if multiple other answers get added; especially since the order of the answers can shift depending on votes.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, makes sense.